# Precise positioning of the widget with FractionalOffset

Tags: flutter, dart

When I want to position the widget in Stack via Align, why can I specify a number from 0.0 to 1.0 in the alignment property: FractionalOffset(x, y) with an accuracy of only 1 decimal point? For example, I need to set the x: 0.1222 coordinate.

Flutter will trim the value to 0.1  How can I position the widget more precisely in this case?

*Upd: I guess the question can be closed by using the positioned and recalculating the coordinates*

```
 Positioned(
              top: alignmentY *
                  (window.physicalSize.height / window.devicePixelRatio),
              left: alignmentX *
                  (window.physicalSize.width / window.devicePixelRatio),
```

Comment: flutter does not trim `FractionalOffset` to  1 decimal point - for more see https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/blob/master/packages/flutter_web/lib/src/painting/fractional_offset.dart#L53

Comment: have you tried Positioned Widget?

Comment: @pskink I took a screenshot to show that the flutter is trimming the value

 [link](https://i.imgur.com/yFAPMg2.png)

Comment: @Sahandevs Yes, of course. But there I have to recalculate the values.

Comment: did you see the link I posted? line 195?

Comment: @pskink Yes, I get it. Thank you. 
I guess the question can be closed by using the positioned and recalculating the coordinates 
~~~
Positioned(
          top: alignmentY *
              (window.physicalSize.height / window.devicePixelRatio),
          left: alignmentX *
              (window.physicalSize.width / window.devicePixelRatio),
~~~

Comment: You can still use `FractionalOffset` - as you saw there is no trimming

Comment: @pskink I've tried it already. The widget still shifts with 0.1 step.